# How can I check if a particular port is open from one site to another?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, firewall, port, port-forwarding

I want to know if port 139 TCP is open from a server on one domain to another. How would I do this?

I know that I can use Telnet to test port 25 to a server with Exchange installed - but that only works because Exchange answers the telnet request - is that right?

How do you test the link if there is no program on the other end that will respond to telnet for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out nmap: http://nmap.org/

nmap -p 25 example.com

Cheers

Comment: That's brilliant - thanks.
The line actually needed to be "nmap example.com -Pn139" but that worked perfectly. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
telnet myserver.com 139
```

If you're on a Linux/Unix box, I recommend you to check nc

```
man nc
```

Comment: As I said in my original post this will only work if there is a program on the remote side that is ready to accept 139 requests - isn't that right? What if there is no such program?